# calling a parent class constructor from a subclass in python

Tags: python, class, constructor

I am trying to use subclasses of a python class to implement [more] specific behaviour for a [very simple] game.

Here's some classes used in the code declared at the beginning:

```
from enum import Enum

class direction(Enum):
    LEFT = ','
    RIGHT = '.'

class bomb:
    def __init__(self,xval,yval):
        self.x = xval
        self.y = yval
        self.fired = False
```

After these classes, here's the root class of the class that [seems to be] causing a problem:

```
class character:
    # default constructor
    def __init__(self,xval,yval):
        self.x = xval
        self.y = yval
        self.alive = True
        self.bomb = bomb(self.x,self.y)
    def fire_bomb(self):
        self.bomb.x = self.x
        self.bomb.y = self.y
        self.bomb.fired = True
```

and here's the subclass where the error appears subclass:

```
class baddie(character):
    def __init__(self,xval,yval):
        super().__init__(xval, yval) 
        self.currentDirection = direction().RIGHT
```

But when I try and create an array of baddies:

```
baddie_list = [baddie(1,1)], baddie(3,1), baddie(5,1), baddie(7,1), baddie(9,1), baddie(11,1)]
```

it's bombing out with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinvaders.py", line 59, in <module>
    baddie_list = [baddie(1,1)] #, baddie(3,1), baddie(5,1), baddie(7,1), baddie(9,1), 
baddie(11,1)]
  File "pyinvaders.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.currentDirection = direction().RIGHT
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The error appears to occur when creating the array of baddie objects, which leads me to examine the constructor for the baddie.

Can anyone give some pointers on how I call the parent class constructor from the child class?

thanks heaps,

David

Comment: what is `direction()`? `super().__init__(xval, yval) ` is executed without error and the problem is on the next line - `self.currentDirection = direction().RIGHT`. Please, provide [mre].

Comment: so as buran stated, the code that is throwing the error is not included in your example. The issue is with the line `self.currentDirection = direction().RIGHT`

Comment: thanks heaps guys - I have edited the question to add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all that, the error wasn't in the call to the parent constructor at all!

The error was on the line:

```
self.currentDirection = direction().RIGHT
```

which should be:

```
self.currentDirection = direction.RIGHT
```

That is, no brackets needed [smacks forehead with palm].

Thanks buran [especially].  You were spot on right - that's where the problem was!